# Change D3 tooltip background color based on object being hovered over

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am attempting to create a D3 tooltip, using the d3-tip library, that changes color based on the background color of the element being hovered over. Here is what I have so far:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      chartType: 'shade'
    }
  }
  
  
  drawLegend(hexBorderColor, fontColor) {
    
    var effLegend = d3.select('g.legend')
    var heatScale = d3.scaleQuantize().domain([0, 1]).range(['#1147FF', '#86D8FF', '#FFEF67', '#FF7D11', '#F30000'])

    var hexbin = d3.hexbin()
      .radius(1.5)
      .x(d => d.key[0]) 
      .y(d => d.key[1]); 

    const legendHoverText = ['Bot 20%', '20% - 40%', '40% - 60%', '60% - 80%', 'Top 20%'];
    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-1, 0])
      .html((d,i) => `<p>${legendHoverText[i]}</p>`)
    effLegend.call(tip)
    
 
    // draw the 5 colorful hexagons (add tip.show and .hide here)
    effLegend.selectAll('path')
      .data(heatScale.range())
      .enter().append('path')
        .attr("transform", (d,i) => `translate(${10+(1+i*2)},10)`)
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
        .attr('d', hexbin.hexagon(0))
          .transition().duration(1000)
          .attr('d', hexbin.hexagon(1.1))
          .attr('stroke', hexBorderColor)
          .attr('stroke-width', 0.175)
          .style('fill', d => d)
    // =====
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
  
    const chart = d3.select('.chart')
      .attr('width', 325)
      .attr('height', 300)
      .attr("viewBox", "0, 0, " + 30 + ", " + 30 + "")

    this.drawLegend('#AAA', '#EEE')    
  }
  
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.chartType);
    return(
      <div className='container'>
        <svg className='chart'>
     <g className="legend"></g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
/* D3 ToolTip */
/* ========== */
.d3-tip {
  line-height: .5;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px 8px;
/*   background: rgba(125, 125, 25, 0.8); */
  color: #444;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #444;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: blue;
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
/* ===== */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js">
</script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hexbin.v0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.8.0-alpha.1/d3-tip.js"></script>

<div id='root'>
  Work for gods sake!
</div>
```

The output is 5 hexagons with the 5 colors in the heatScale() range. I would like for the background color (currently all white), and later font color (currently all black) of the tooltip to change conditional on the background color of the hexagon that is being hovered over. For now, I'd simply like the tooltip background color to be the same as the hexagon color that is being hovered over. However, I am struggling to do this, and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is just selecting the `d3.tip` div and setting the background colour to the bound datum:

```
d3.select(".d3-tip").style("background-color", d);
```

Here is the updated code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      chartType: 'shade'
    }
  }
  
  
  drawLegend(hexBorderColor, fontColor) {
    
    var effLegend = d3.select('g.legend')
    var heatScale = d3.scaleQuantize().domain([0, 1]).range(['#1147FF', '#86D8FF', '#FFEF67', '#FF7D11', '#F30000'])

    var hexbin = d3.hexbin()
      .radius(1.5)
      .x(d => d.key[0]) 
      .y(d => d.key[1]); 

    const legendHoverText = ['Bot 20%', '20% - 40%', '40% - 60%', '60% - 80%', 'Top 20%'];
    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-1, 0])
      .html((d,i) => {
      d3.select(".d3-tip").style("background-color", d);
      return `<p>${legendHoverText[i]}</p>`})
    effLegend.call(tip)
    
 
    // draw the 5 colorful hexagons (add tip.show and .hide here)
    effLegend.selectAll('path')
      .data(heatScale.range())
      .enter().append('path')
        .attr("transform", (d,i) => `translate(${10+(1+i*2)},10)`)
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
        .attr('d', hexbin.hexagon(0))
          .transition().duration(1000)
          .attr('d', hexbin.hexagon(1.1))
          .attr('stroke', hexBorderColor)
          .attr('stroke-width', 0.175)
          .style('fill', d => d)
    // =====
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
  
    const chart = d3.select('.chart')
      .attr('width', 325)
      .attr('height', 300)
      .attr("viewBox", "0, 0, " + 30 + ", " + 30 + "")

    this.drawLegend('#AAA', '#EEE')    
  }
  
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.chartType);
    return(
      <div className='container'>
        <svg className='chart'>
     <g className="legend"></g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
/* D3 ToolTip */
/* ========== */
.d3-tip {
  line-height: .5;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px 8px;
/*   background: rgba(125, 125, 25, 0.8); */
  color: #444;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #444;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: blue;
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
/* ===== */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js">
</script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hexbin.v0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.8.0-alpha.1/d3-tip.js"></script>

<div id='root'>
  Work for gods sake!
</div>
```

PS: Don't use `d3.tip` for your tooltips, create them yourself. That way you can customise them the way you want.

Comment: A friend suggested for me to use d3-tip - could you share or link an example of how I can create tooltips myself?

Comment: I'm creating my d3 graph as a react component. This graph component updates frequently, and the way in react that I do this is by using the svg *ref* attribute. (I believe this approach allows D3 to do all of DOM manipulations over React). For this reason I didn't want to create a <div> element in my component.

Comment: @Canovice there are several different ways, this one seems to be easy: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35652760/5768908